# Unix/bash/Shell: How to Find Files from a List and Merge Them into One File

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to merge specific files (`XXXXXXX_Abstract_TOC.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter1.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter2.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter3.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter4.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Conclusion.txt`) into one file based on specific numbers that come from a text file(**/util_files/list_NRPs.txt**).

Note: X is `[0-9]` digit

The **list_NRPs.txt** contains as follows:

```
0030001
0030002
0030004
...
```

In **/All_Files** folder, I have files as follows:

```
0030001_Abstract_TOC.txt
0030001_Chapter1.txt
0030001_Chapter2.txt
0030001_Chapter3.txt
0030001_Chapter4.txt
0030001_Conclusion.txt
0030002_Abstract_TOC.txt
0030002_Chapter1.txt
0030002_Chapter2.txt
0030002_Chapter3.txt
0030002_Chapter4.txt
0030002_Conclusion.txt
0030004_Abstract_TOC.txt
0030004_Chapter1.txt
0030004_Chapter2.txt
0030004_Chapter3.txt
0030004_Chapter4.txt
0030004_Conclusion.txt
...
```

For each XXXXXXX from **list_NRPs.txt** I would like to merge `XXXXXXX_Abstract_TOC.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter1.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter2.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter3.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Chapter4.txt`, `XXXXXXX_Conclusion.txt` into `XXXXXXX_All.txt`.

The final process in **/All_Files** folder would be:

```
0030001_Abstract_TOC.txt
0030001_Chapter1.txt
0030001_Chapter2.txt
0030001_Chapter3.txt
0030001_Chapter4.txt
0030001_Conclusion.txt
0030001_All.txt
0030002_Abstract_TOC.txt
0030002_Chapter1.txt
0030002_Chapter2.txt
0030002_Chapter3.txt
0030002_Chapter4.txt
0030002_Conclusion.txt
0030002_All.txt 
0030004_Abstract_TOC.txt
0030004_Chapter1.txt
0030004_Chapter2.txt
0030004_Chapter3.txt
0030004_Chapter4.txt
0030004_Conclusion.txt
0030004_All.txt
...
```

I would like start with `cat ../util_files/list_NRPs.txt | xargs` but I do not know how to proceed.

How can I do that?

Comment: Bad idea store the `All` together with `parts` (chapters,toc) in the same directory. In the subsequent runs, you will need exclude the All from the list and complicating the globbing (wildcards).

Comment: Noted, thank @jm666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use globbing to concatenate multiple files matching each line in `list_NRPs.txt` file:

```
while read -r ch; do
    cat "/All_Files/$ch"* > "/All_Files/${ch}_All.txt"
done < /util_files/list_NRPs.txt
```